# Issues with INSERT onto a mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write onto a database using PHP and mySQL but it's giving me an error message and i'm not seeing anything wrong with the code. I'm using MAMP therefore a port is required. Please help!!. There are 2 pages: signup.php & checklogin.php (where the database connection string is)

**checklogin.php**

```
<?
//Database connection
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$database = 'siteproject';


try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;port=8889;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("Connection Failed" .$e->getMessage()); 
    }

?>
```

signup.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<? 
// Header page of the entire site
include ("header.php");
require ("checklogin.php");
?>

<?
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
    $sql = "INSERT INTO siteUsers (username, pword) VALUES (:userName, :Pass)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userName', $_Post["username"]);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Pass', $_Post["password"]);
        if ($stmt->execute()):
                die('Successfully added');
        ELSE:
                echo ($_POST['username']);
                die('<h1>Data wasnt inserted</h1>');
        endif;

endif;

?>
<body>

<div align="center"><h1>Register Page</h1></div>
<form action="signup.php" method="POST">

  <div align="center">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="username">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_password">
  <input type="submit">
  </div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for the help,
Lee

Comment: `$_Post` is not `$_POST` what is the error message? Passwords should be hashed.

Comment: And we should just imagine what this error message could be?

Comment: My apologies guys. The error is "Data Wasnt entered" Which is the ELSE I setup if the data is not inserted into the database.